# PHP / Datatables: numbers getting sorted as text

Tags: php, formatting, numbers, datatables, number-formatting

I am using Datatables to style a table that I fill with PHP.

Everything works as intended except for a column containing amounts. 
If I click on the Datatables column header for this column in order to sort the table by this column it sorts it but only as text instead of numbers so that 20 appears before 3 etc.

Is there a way I can prevent this in PHP by changing the format ?

**Example cell:**

```
<td class="colAmount ralign"><?php echo number_format(doubleval($requests->amount), 2, ".", ","); ?></td>
```

If an amount in my database ($requests->amount) is e.g. 100000 then the above would format this as 100,000.00 as I need to display it with the thousands and decimal separators - this is then probably interpreted as text.

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Datatables [Orthogonal Data](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data) feature for this. This way, you can use different formats for display and sorting. There are two approaches here, I would go for the [HTML 5](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data#HTML-5) style, which uses `data` attributes (from the example there):

```
<tr>
    <td data-search="Tiger Nixon">T. Nixon</td>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td data-order="1303682400">Mon 25th Apr 11</td>
    <td data-order="3120">$3,120/m</td>
</tr>
```

In this example the data for the last two columns would be sorted using the `data-order` attributes. There should be no further configuration needed, `Datatables` should detect these attributes automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to your SQL query the follow:

> ORDER BY YourField + 0

This will output it ordered as number.

Comment: Thanks. I would need to find a way without using SQL as this only applies if a user wants to search the table by a column, i.e. by using  Datatables built-in sorting function.

Comment: Do you want order your result using PHP?

Comment: No, I just want to format it as a number so that Datatables will sort it accordingly.

Comment: In your table structure, which is the "type" of your column?